# How can a program read console input after input redirection?

Tags: command-line, io-redirection

I've always found the command-line `mysql` utility to be a bit surprising, because you can do this:

```
gzcat dumpfile.sql.gz | mysql -u <user> -p <options>
```

and `mysql` will prompt you for a password. Now, `stdin` in `mysql` is redirected -- one would expect it to read the password from the dumpfile. Instead, it somehow bypasses `stdin` and goes straight for the terminal. `ssh` does the same kind of thing.

I suspect this is some sort of `/dev/tty` or `/dev/pty` magic, but I'd appreciate a proper explanation for this apparent magic :) (and why these programs can do it on any platform, even Windows).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you surmise, it is using `/dev/tty`, which is specified this way:

> In each process, [`/dev/tty` is] a synonym for the controlling terminal associated with the process group of that process, if any. It is useful for programs or shell procedures that wish to be sure of writing messages to or reading data from the terminal no matter how output has been redirected. It can also be used for programs that demand the name of a file for output, when typed output is desired and it is tiresome to find out what terminal is currently in use.

No real "magic" beyond that.

[[link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/files.html)]

Comment: Windows doesn't have that though, does it?

Comment: @nneonneo: No, it doesn't. This is *nix functionality. The Windows API provides a different mechanism (for which see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073.aspx)). It's not as though there were a single `mysql` program that runs on both types of systems; the *nix version of `mysql` uses the *nix functionality, and the Windows version uses the Windows functionality.